# Why does my generated SVG get a fixed with and a height?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am trying to recreate github's autogenerated avatar system for a school project, using SVG and javscript. However I get a css bug. Whenever I create an empty svg tag and then append the svg element to the svg tag the image svg gets a fixed position with a fixed width and height. Why is there a way to fix this and how?

avatar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test for the avatar script</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg></svg>
    <script src="scripts/avatar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Avatar.js

```
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

let svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
let avatar = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");

let base_width = 800
let base_height = 800

avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "x", 25);
avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "y", 25);
avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "width", base_width);
avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "height", base_height);
avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "green"); 

svg.appendChild(avatar)
```

[image: Image of the svg not working properly]

As seen as in the image the svg has a width and a height of 300x150 px even though I have not specified a with and a height. But the rect element has a width and a height of 800x800 px. Why does this happen?

Comment: 300 x 150 is the default size. To change it you will need to have a width and height attributes or even better a viewBox attribute. You also can change the size from CSS. https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/#:~:text=The%20default%20300%C3%97150,the%20default%20size%20for%20SVG

Answer (score 2):

As @enxaneta suggested, give your SVG a `viewBox` and you can scale it to any size you want.  Here I've scaled it down to 80x80.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

let svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
let avatar = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");

let base_width = 800
let base_height = 800

avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "x", 25);
avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "y", 25);
avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "width", base_width);
avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "height", base_height);
avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "green"); 

svg.appendChild(avatar)
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"></svg>
```